# Dictionary entries all are the same after enumerating Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am using enumerate to get the row number for each row to use as `image_id` but it keeps returning the length of rows and not the index.

```
def get_detectron_format(self):
  """Returns the dataset in the Detectron2 list(dict) format"""
  csv = self.get_data_csv()
  dataset_dicts = []
  record = dict()
  for i, (index, data) in enumerate(csv.iterrows()):
    record['file_name'] = os.path.join(self.data_root, data['Path'])
    record['image_id'] = i
    record['height'] = data['Height']
    record['width'] = data['Width']
    
    objs = []
    obj= {
      'bbox': [data['Roi.X1'], data['Roi.Y1'], data['Roi.X2'], data['Roi.Y2']],
      'bbox_mode': BoxMode.XYXY_ABS,
      'category_id': data['Roi.X1'] - 1,
      'iscrowd': 0
    }
  
    objs.append(obj)
    record['annotations'] = objs
    dataset_dicts.append(record)
  return dataset_dicts
```

When I print out the first item in the dataset:

```
gtsr = GTSR_Dataset()
dataset = gtsr.get_detectron_format()[0]
print(dataset)
```

I get:

```
{
'file_name': '/content/drive/My Drive/Datasets/german_traffic_sign_recognition/Train/42/00042_00007_00029.png', 
'image_id': 39208, 
'height': 69, 
'width': 68, 
'annotations': [{'bbox': [7, 6, 62, 63], 
                 'bbox_mode': <BoxMode.XYXY_ABS: 0>, 
                 'category_id': 6, 
                 'iscrowd': 0}]}
```

..where `image_id` should be `0`. Why is this? How do I get the row number (index)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dictionary `record` is being initialized before the for loop (*Line 5: `record = dict()`*). The same record is being updated multiple times. This will need to be moved inside the for loop.

When the `dataset_dicts.append(record)` is being done, the same address of record is being appended to `dataset_dicts` so basically you have multiple entries of the last record.

Comment: You so smart :D

Comment: Not smart, Have just done the same code mistake multiple times.  Learning the hard way :)

Answer (score 1):

use `objs.append(obj.copy())` this will store the data instead of `id(obj)` your problem will be solved.

Comment: Love new ways of thinking! Great input! Anything I should be concerned about when taking this direction? Seems like the only issue would be more objects if the df is massive.. but I probably should not use `iterrows()` on massive dfs

Comment: Thank you, both of the solution will work fine. you don't need to worry, you can use whichever you like.. in @Prashanth Mariswamy you are creating a new `dict` object every iteration... in my solution.. you are overwriting the initial `dict` with new values.

Comment: yes, why dont you try `csv.to_dict(orient="records")`

Comment: I will look into that. Thank you! In all honsesty I probably have a lot of optimization to do to speed up my Deep Learning dataloading :)